# Blazor WebAssembly null reference after upgrade to .NET6

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-6.0, blazorise

I have a Blazor Web Assembly project that I started in .NET5. I am using Blazorise and it is working well for me.
A few weeks ago, I upgraded to .NET6, initially within the main project and found that I was getting a strange error.
Shortly after loading the index page, after some back and forth to the server getting user details etc. I am getting an unhandled exception with a bunch of console messages which don't really indicate (to me) where the error is...
[image]
I have used an image to condense the messages. I can make the detail available if needed. I have followed some of the links and they take me deep into JS territory.

The strange things about this are:

a) This didn't occur till I updated to NET6 - initially I thought it could be that I had updated wrongly, so I rebuilt the App from the ground up using a NET6 Template. The error came back.

b) I have spent days using a process of elimination to be able to make the error 'go away' - details follow:
I have several components I am using for forms:
-an EditUserForm
-an OrgansationForm
-an AddressForm

They are all components  and use Blazorise Modals. Here is the EditUserForm:

```
@namespace blah.Client.Components.Forms
<Modal @ref="modalRef">
<ModalContent IsCentered="true">
    <ModalHeader>
        <ModalTitle>Editing @editUser.FullName</ModalTitle>
        <CloseButton Clicked="@HideModal" />
    </ModalHeader>
    <ModalBody MaxHeight="50">

        <div class="bg-light">
            @if (editUser.IsComplete)
            {
                <p>Your Information is Complete - Make any changes and Press the 'Save' button.</p>
            }
            else
            {
                <p>Your Information is Incomplete - Please ensure you have completed at least your Name, Address, Mobile Number and Gender.</p>

            }
        </div>

        <EditForm Model="@editUser" @onchange="() => Refresh()">
            <DataAnnotationsValidator />
            <Field>
                <FieldLabel>Title</FieldLabel>
                <TextEdit Placeholder="Enter Title..." @bind-Text="@editUser.Title" />
            </Field>
            <Field>
                <FieldLabel>First Name</FieldLabel>
                <TextEdit Placeholder="Enter First Name..." @bind-Text="@editUser.FirstName" />
            </Field>
            <Field>
                <FieldLabel>Middle Name</FieldLabel>
                <TextEdit Placeholder="Enter Middle Name..." @bind-Text="@editUser.MiddleName" />
            </Field>

            <Field>
                <FieldLabel>Last Name</FieldLabel>
                <TextEdit Placeholder="Enter Last Name..." @bind-Text="@editUser.FamilyName" />
            </Field>

            <Field>
                <FieldLabel>Email</FieldLabel>
                <TextEdit Placeholder="Enter Email..." @bind-Text="@editUser.Email" />
            </Field>

            <Field>
                <FieldLabel>Phone No</FieldLabel>
                <TextEdit Placeholder="Enter Phone No..." @bind-Text="@editUser.PhoneNumber" />
            </Field>

            <Field>
                <FieldLabel>Date of Birth</FieldLabel>
                <InputDate @bind-Value="@editUser.DoB" />
            </Field>

            <Field>
                <FieldLabel>Gender</FieldLabel>
                <Blazorise.Select TValue="AvailablePlayer.Shared.Enums.Gender" @bind-SelectedValue="@editUser.Gender">
                    @foreach (AvailablePlayer.Shared.Enums.Gender gendertype in Enum.GetValues(typeof(AvailablePlayer.Shared.Enums.Gender)))
                    {
                        var gtypetemp = gendertype;
                        <Blazorise.SelectItem Value="@gtypetemp">
                            @Enum.GetName(typeof(AvailablePlayer.Shared.Enums.Gender), gtypetemp).Replace('_', ' ');
                        </Blazorise.SelectItem>
                    }
                </Blazorise.Select>
            </Field>

            <Field>
                <FieldLabel>Address</FieldLabel>
                <div>@getlongaddress()</div>
                @if (editUser.Address != null && !editUser.Address.IsComplete)
                {
                    <p>The Address is incomplete, please edit</p>
                    <Button Color="Color.Danger" Clicked="@EditAddress">Edit Address</Button>
                }
                else
                {
                    <Button Color="Color.Secondary" Clicked="@EditAddress">Edit Address</Button>
                }
            </Field>
            <Field>
                <FieldLabel>Sign up as Player and Accept Player T's & C's</FieldLabel>
                <InputCheckbox @bind-Value="Isplayer">Accept Player Terms <a href="Identity/Account/PlayerConditions.html">which you can see here</a></InputCheckbox>
            </Field>
            @if (Isplayer)
            {
                <Button Color="Color.Secondary" Clicked="@EditPlayer">Edit Player</Button>
            }
            <Field>
                <FieldLabel>Sign up as a member of an organisation and Accept Member T's & C's</FieldLabel>
                <InputCheckbox @bind-Value="Ismember">Accept Member Terms </InputCheckbox>
                <a href="Identity/Account/PlayerConditions.html">which you can see here</a>
            </Field>
            @if (Ismember)
            {
                <Button Color="Color.Secondary" Clicked="@EditOrgMember">Edit Membership</Button>
            }
        </EditForm>
        <AuthorizeView Roles="Administrator">
            <Authorized Context="Auth">
                <div class="bg-light">
                    <p>(Note: to remove Player Role also untick the 'Accept Player Terms' Box)</p>
                    @foreach (rolebool rolething in rolelist)
                    {
                        <div>
                            <Check TValue="bool" @bind-Checked="rolething.userisin">@rolething.role </Check>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
            </Authorized>
        </AuthorizeView>
    </ModalBody>
    <ModalFooter>
        <Button Color="Color.Secondary" Clicked="@HideModal">Close</Button>
        <Button Color="Color.Primary" Clicked="@SaveAsync">Save Changes</Button>
    </ModalFooter>
  </ModalContent>
</Modal>
<CascadingValue Name="EditAddress" Value="@editUser.Address">
   <AddressForm @ref="addressform" OnAddressSaved="AddressSaved"></AddressForm>
</CascadingValue>

<EditPlayerForm @ref="playereditform" OnPlayerSaved="Refresh" />

 <OrganisationForm @ref="organisationForm" />

 <Snackbar @ref="snackbar">
     <SnackbarBody>
         @StatusMessage
     </SnackbarBody>
 </Snackbar>
```

The code is in a seperate file and has many functions, so for brevity I just show the basics here:

```
namespace blah.Client.Components.Forms
{
public partial class EditUserForm : ComponentBase
    {

        [Inject] UserService UserService { get; set; }

        ...some stuff...

        //private bool _ismember;
        protected bool Ismember;

        AddressForm addressform = new AddressForm();
        EditPlayerForm playereditform = new EditPlayerForm();
        OrganisationForm organisationForm = new OrganisationForm();

        ...some stuff...

        protected void EditAddress()
        {
            addressform.ShowModal();
        }

        private void AddressSaved(AddressDTO address)
        {
            editUser.Address = address;
            this.StateHasChanged();   // To reload the address.
        }

        public void Refresh()
        {
            this.StateHasChanged();
        }

    }
```

This is the OrganisationForm:

```
        @namespace blah.Client.Components.Forms
    <Modal @ref="modalRef">
        <ModalContent IsCentered="true">
            <ModalHeader>
                <ModalTitle>Editing Organisation</ModalTitle>
                <CloseButton Clicked="@HideModal" />
            </ModalHeader>
            <ModalBody MaxHeight="50">
                <EditForm Model="@editOrganisation" @onchange="() => Refresh()">
                    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
                    <Field>
                        <FieldLabel>Organisation Name</FieldLabel>
                        <TextEdit Placeholder="blah..." @bind-Text="@editOrganisation.Name" />
                    </Field>


                    <Field>
                        <FieldLabel>Business Address</FieldLabel>
                        <div>@getlongaddress(editOrganisation.BusinessAddress)</div>
                        @if (editOrganisation.BusinessAddress != null && !editOrganisation.BusinessAddress.IsComplete)
                        {
                            <p>The Address is incomplete, please edit</p>
                            <Button Color="Color.Danger" Clicked="() => EditAddress(editOrganisation.BusinessAddress)">Edit Main Address</Button>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <Button Color="Color.Secondary" Clicked="() => EditAddress(editOrganisation.BusinessAddress)">Edit Main Address</Button>
                        }
                    </Field>
                    <Field>
                        <FieldLabel>Date Joined</FieldLabel>
                        <DateEdit @bind-Date="editOrganisation.DateJoined" />

                    </Field>
                </EditForm>

            </ModalBody>
            <ModalFooter>
                <Button Color="Color.Secondary" Clicked="@HideModal">Close</Button>
                <Button Color="Color.Primary" Clicked="@SaveAsync">Save</Button>
            </ModalFooter>
        </ModalContent>
    </Modal>

    <AddressForm @ref="addressform" OnAddressSaved="AddressSaved"></AddressForm>

    <Snackbar @ref="snackbar">
        <SnackbarBody>
            @StatusMessage
        </SnackbarBody>
    </Snackbar>
```

...and the code for the OrganisationForm (with some functions removed)

```
    namespace blah.Client.Components.Forms
    {
        public partial class OrganisationForm : ComponentBase
        {
            [Inject] ExecService ExecService { get; set; }

            // reference to the modal component
            protected Modal modalRef = new Modal();

            AddressForm addressform = new AddressForm();
            DatePicker<DateTime?> datepicker = new DatePicker<DateTime?>();

            [Parameter]
            public EventCallback<OrganisationDTO> OnOrganisationSaved { get; set; }

            public OrganisationDTO editOrganisation { get; set; } = new OrganisationDTO();


            private void AddressSaved(AddressDTO address)
            {
                editOrganisation.BusinessAddress = address;
                this.StateHasChanged();   // To reload the address.
            }

            protected void EditAddress(AddressDTO addresstoedit)
            {
                addressform.editAddress = addresstoedit;
                addressform.ShowModal();
            }

            protected async Task SaveAsync()
            {
                editOrganisation = await ExecService.AddUpdateOrganisationAsync(editOrganisation);
                StatusMessage = editOrganisation.Status.Reason;
                await snackbar.Show();
                HideModal();
                await OnOrganisationSaved.InvokeAsync(editOrganisation);
            }

        }
    }
```

and finally the AddressForm:

```
            @namespace blah.Client.Components.Forms
              <Modal @ref="modalRef">
              <ModalContent IsCentered="true">
                  <ModalHeader>
                      <ModalTitle>Editing Address</ModalTitle>
                      <CloseButton Clicked="@HideModal" />
                  </ModalHeader>
                  <ModalBody MaxHeight="50">
                      <div class="bg-light">
                          @if (editAddress.IsComplete)
                          {
                              <p>Your Address is Complete - Make any changes and Press the 'Save' button.</p>
                          }
                          else
                          {
                              <p>Your Address is Incomplete - Please ensure you have at least your Number, Street and PostCode.</p>
                          }
                      </div>
                <EditForm Model="@editAddress" @onchange="() => checkaddress()">
                    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
                    <Field>
                        <FieldLabel>No. Name or Building</FieldLabel>
                        <TextEdit Placeholder="Enter House No, Name Building..." @bind-Text="@editAddress.Line1"/>
                    </Field>
                    <Field>
                        <FieldLabel>Street</FieldLabel>
                        <TextEdit Placeholder="Enter Street..." @bind-Text="@editAddress.Line2" />
                    </Field>
                    <Field>
                        <FieldLabel>Town/City</FieldLabel>
                        <TextEdit Placeholder="Enter Town/City..." @bind-Text="@editAddress.Line3" />
                    </Field>
                    <Field>
                        <FieldLabel>Region/State</FieldLabel>
                        <TextEdit Placeholder="Enter Region/State..." @bind-Text="@editAddress.Line4" />
                    </Field>

                    <Field>
                        <FieldLabel>Post Code</FieldLabel>
                        <TextEdit Placeholder="Enter Post Code..." @bind-Text="@editAddress.PostCode" />
                    </Field>
                </EditForm>
            </ModalBody>
            <ModalFooter>
                <Button Color="Color.Secondary" Clicked="@HideModal">Close</Button>
                <Button Color="Color.Primary" Clicked="@SaveAsync">Save</Button>
            </ModalFooter>
        </ModalContent>
    </Modal>
```

... and the AddressForm code:

```
              namespace blah.Client.Components.Forms
          {
              public partial class AddressForm : ComponentBase
              {
                  // reference to the modal component
                  protected Modal add_modal = new Modal();

                  [CascadingParameter(Name = "EditAddress")]
                  AddressDTO editAddress { get; set; } = new AddressDTO();
  
                  [Parameter]  
                  public EventCallback<AddressDTO> OnAddressSaved { get; set; } 


                  // Since this is going to be usually called from another form feed back the address 
                  //  by way of this event.
                  async Task SaveAsync()
                  {
                      await OnAddressSaved.InvokeAsync(editAddress);
                      await add_modal.Hide();
                  }

                  // Display functions
                  public void ShowModal()
                  {
                     add_modal.Show();
                  }

                  public void HideModal()
                  {
                      add_modal.Hide();
                  }

                  public void checkaddress()
                  {
                      this.StateHasChanged();
                  }
              }
          }
```

...
I have tried many things, but I keep coming back to the error message that I don't really understand fully as it looks like something is going on with a null in the JS interop but I'm unclear.

I can make the problem go away by reducing the AddressForm to simply this:

```
      @namespace blah.Client.Components.Forms
      <h1>Address Form</h1>
      <Modal @ref="add_modal">
          <ModalContent IsCentered="true">
              <h1>Address Form</h1>
          </ModalContent>
      </Modal>
```

err most of the time.. then it has come back, although it is difficult to keep track because the Chrome debugger sometimes caches stuff and I have to remember to refresh with the cache off...
If I remove the '@ref="add_modal"' from the Modal definition it has always worked.

I know this is weird and most of the time there is a clue in the error how to find the problem. This seems to come and go, and feels it might be timing related. The error always takes a few seconds to appear after all the rendering has finished, so its like a short timeout or failed promise in JS type of thing.

I have tried many things but the code hasn't really changed since I upgraded to NET6 (along with the other components). Another possibility would be if I could add an exception handler maybe and break on it or write my own message, however, I am not sure where to put that?

I am looking for some pointers of how to track this down tbh as I am pretty much at wits end. The error may be staring me in the face in the messages, but I don't see it.

Many thanks
Brett

Comment: Just to ask, because it's a common pitfall: did you clean & remove all obj en bin and .vs directories after going from net5 to net6? Some remnants can ruin your day.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with .NET 6, Blazorise and Blazor WASM. I've been using all these for over a year (yes, .NET 6 Preview 1 and later). Errors like these are typically caused when trying to bind to a null property or object. And yes, the exception doesn't help at all. Try commenting out all fields, until your code runs again, then uncomment them little by little until you find which one caused the problem

Comment: @JHBonarius - Yes I did. I rebuilt the app from scratch with a new NET6 template.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I never said there is anything wrong, except that my code worked with NET5 and some error, that may have been there before but hidden has emerged with NET6. Normally with an error lije the one you describe, the exception will point to at least the file and often the line of code or razor that is the culprit. This error is just singularly unhelpful. Thankyou for the suggestion, but that is what I have been doing now for a few weeks on and off. Cheers ...

Comment: In that case post a *minimal* example that reproduces the problem. Please mention the exact Blazorise version as well. Blazorise is going through some major breaking changes lately despite the minor version changes. `0.9.5` is the first version that fully supports .NET 6 and introduced significant changes, including function name changes and moving from Bootstrap 4 to 5.

Comment: Will do, I have been speaking to Stsrki on Gitter too.. I am pretty sure it is up to speed but I'll check again. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recently upgraded a `blazor` project to `.net6` and had the same issue. One of my projects was failing to build for no apparent reason saying metadata files were missing. There were no other surface errors. I ended up finding a hidden compiler error in my project that VS was not displaying. Code in `.razor` files doesn’t seem to be monitored by the IDE unless the file is open. I opened all razor files and like magic the real error appeared in the error window.

I also had console errors from code in updated packages. I looked at the updates made to the packages to see what might cause those. Some functions in packages had been modified and given overloads I needed to switch to and that got rid of my other errors.

If you have a good folder and file structure in your project a fast way to do this is to open all files in a folder that contains razor files and wait a few seconds for errors to pop up. Close them if none pop up and move to the next folder.
There may be multiple errors so keep opening files and resolving errors when they pop up until you have gone through every folder.

It takes a little time For a large project but it’s not  that bad.